# Installing vaadin-addons with spring roo fails with a maven compile

Tags: gwt, maven, spring-roo, vaadin, add-on

I am using Spring Source Tool Suite version 2.8, Maven version 3.0.3 and my Maven-Eclipse plugin is all up to date. I have a Vaadin project and i am trying to install custom add-ons using Spring ROO's command line and everything works perfect until i run the command:
My pom.xml file shows no errors and i have included my custom widgetset to web.xml file?

```
Vaadin Widgetset create
```

The ROO shell is able to update my pom.xml file to add the necessary files. The first ROO command: Failed

```
Vaadin widgetset update

[CODE]roo> vaadin widgetset update 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
4 KB   
5 KB   
9 KB   
11 KB   

Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml

Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (11 KB at 13.0 KB/sec)
4 KB    
8 KB   
12 KB   
13 KB   
17 KB   
19 KB   

Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (19 KB at 25.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.154s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 05 13:42:24 CST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'vaadin' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/warz07/.m2/repository), spring-maven-release (http://maven.springframework.org/release), spring-maven-milestone (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone), spring-roo-repository (http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release), central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException[/CODE]
```

I then ran this command : [CODE]vaadin widgetset create[/CODE]

```
vaadin widgetset create


Updated SRC_MAIN_WEBAPP/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
4 KB   
5 KB   
9 KB   
11 KB   

Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (11 KB at 18.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml

Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml

4 KB    
8 KB   
9 KB   
13 KB   
17 KB   
18 KB   
19 KB   

Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (19 KB at 21.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.509s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 05 13:45:01 CST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'vaadin' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/warz07/.m2/repository), spring-maven-release (http://maven.springframework.org/release), spring-maven-milestone (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone), spring-roo-repository (http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release), central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
Updated ROOT/pom.xml [added dependencies com.google.gwt:gwt-user:2.3.0, javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA:sources; added plugin gwt-maven-plugin; added plugin vaadin-maven-plugin]
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/org/bixin/dugsi/client/managed/request
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/org/bixin/dugsi/client/managed/request/ApplicationRequestFactory.java
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/org/bixin/dugsi/client/scaffold/gae
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/org/bixin/dugsi/client/scaffold/gae/GaeHelper.java
Updated ROOT/pom.xml [removed plugin gwt-maven-plugin; added plugin gwt-maven-plugin; added dependency com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.5.1][/CODE]
```

Is there any other way with or without using the roo shell to install vaadin add-ons using maven?

Comment: no help from vaadin team about this. Still unable to use custom addons with spring roo and maven

Comment: I'm not using ROO but are you trying to add custom add-ons from the Vaadin add-on directory, or build your own add-on? If it's the first case then it seems your pom.xml doesn't contain the Vaadin add-on repository.

Comment: I am trying to add custom add-ons from the vaadin directory, i have verified under the <Repositories> section that vaadin addon repo is there. I got it figured out but i did not use spring roo to fix it, in fact using roo will corrupt the pom.xml file and delete the gwt.xml references.

Comment: Okay, I'm glad you have it sorted out!